# CakePHP Using requestHandler and isAjax

Tags: php, cakephp

I have the following code (I'm also calling the RequestHandler component) in my controller:

```
function popup()
    {   
        if ($this->requestHandler->isAjax())
        {
            // jazz
        }
        else
        {
            $this->cakeError('error403');
        }
    }
```

The idea is that if a user tries to access the page directly then they will get a 403 or if it's loaded in a popup via AJAX then all be fine. However I get the following errors:

```
Notice (8): Undefined property: PagesController::$requestHandler [APP/controllers/pages_controller.php, line 103]
Fatal error: Call to a member function isAjax() on a non-object in /Users/cameron/Sites/cameron/app/controllers/pages_controller.php on line 103
```

and line 103 is the if statement

Any ideas what the problem is? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$this->RequestHandler->isAjax();
```

Just a typo.